# How to fine control how a SOAP response type is converted into a PHP type?

Tags: php, xml, soap, php-5.3, soap-client

I'm using the PHP SOAP extension (`SoapClient`) to call a remote operation. Its WSDL type is like:

```
<s:element name="OperationResponse">
    <s:complexType>
        <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="OperationResult">
                <s:complexType mixed="true">
                    <s:sequence>
                        <s:any/>
                    </s:sequence>
                </s:complexType>
            </s:element>
        </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
</s:element>
```

As far as I can understand, the type is "anything". The result of the call is transformed into a nested `stdClass` object, not easy to work with:

```
object(stdClass)[3]
  public 'OperationResult' => 
    object(stdClass)[4]
      public 'any' => string 'xml string here...'
```

(This is actually performed by the SOAP extension itself)

How can I control **how this object is created**? I've tried to pass the `classmap` option to the SOAP client, but it's not working: I get the instance, but properties are `null`.

The problem of **manually parsing the result** is clear. I can create a new `SimpleXmlElement` with the string coming from `$result->OperationResult->any`, but it won't work if the WSDL changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can transform that result in almost anything in PHP via that classmap feature, but the question is if you should, because the same Soap data structures are usually used for both requests and responses. Reuse them!

My general approach is to use the classmap feature to map all those ComplexType structures onto PHP classes. And if that structure does not fit well to the intended use, I have a mapper step that transforms the result in PHP.